# Find the matrix of the restriction $ S = T|_U$, relative to the basis B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

For part i), I showed that T(1,0,0) = (2,2,1) = (1,0,0) + (1,2,1) and T(1,2,1) = (0,-2,-1) = (1,0,0)-(1,2,1), so T(U) is a subset of U.

However I'm unsure how to approach question ii). What is the matrix of the restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Just express with respect to $B$ the image under $T$ of the two vectors in $B$.

Comment: So would that make the matrix ((1,1),(1,-1))? Sorry I can't figure out how to do the matrix format on this site.

Comment: @mathstack, yes.